# Using kendo-pager without kendo-grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to have documentation about kendo-pager?
I just would like to use it without grid but i don't find any documentation regarding it on main site: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/

Into the main kendoGrid component javascript i found:

```
e=r([i.Component({selector:"kendo-pager"
```

But i really don't know about npm module i have to install and how to use it!
Do i have to use "selector" like:

```
<kendo-pager>
```

But what about data binding, data model, events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the pager is not intended to be used outside the Grid component. If you think this is important you can log your request in the [feedback portal](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback)

Comment: Ok i have created a new request: http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback/suggestions/17814475-pager-component